# When the article the is used before theorem names

Tags: definite-articles, mathematics

When writing math papers, one sometimes has to refer to some famous theorems, for instance, the Pythagorean theorem.

Shall I write "by Pythagorean theorem", or "by the Pythagorean theorem". When shall I use the article "the"?

Comment: I am not a mathematician, but did Pythagoras write any theorems other than the one about the square on the hypotenuse? If not, then my inclination would simply be to write *re Pythagoras*.

Comment: The reference is to a unique theorem, so it should be definite: "by the Pythagorean theorem" or "by Pythagoras' theorem". It's like "the binomial theorem" or "the quadratic formula".

Comment: In this case "Pythagorean" is an adjective. Would the answer be the same for names which are not transforms into adjectives, for example: "Poisson process" vs "the Poisson process"?

Answer (score 4):

This Google ngram shows what others have done in published books.

[Google ngram: by Pythagoras ' theorem,by Pythagorean theorem,by the Pythagorean theorem](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by%20Pythagoras%20%27%20theorem%2Cby%20Pythagorean%20theorem%2Cby%20the%20Pythagorean%20theorem&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cby%20Pythagoras%20%27%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20Pythagoras%20%27%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20Pythagoras%20%27%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20Pythagoras%20%27%20Theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20Pythagorean%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cby%20the%20Pythagorean%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bby%20the%20Pythagorean%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20the%20Pythagorean%20theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bby%20the%20Pythagorean%20Theorem%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBy%20the%20Pythagorean%20Theorem%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Notice that 'by Pythagorean theorem' has only one occurrence.

Answer (score -2):

"by Pythagorean Theorem"

For example, "I solved this equation using Pythagorean's Theorem," or, I solved expression 6 by using Pythagorean's Theorem."

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but "Pythagorean's Theorem" is not a valid construction. Maybe "***a*** Pythagorean's Theorem" is theoretically possible, but not for this case.  Anyway, people would be left wondering which Pythagorean.